# How to stop duplicate entries in Google Calendar - Google Script - Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm using a shared google sheet and creating a Sync to Calendar Button.

I'm trying to target one column of cells as start times, one column of cells for end times and one column of cells for titles. All avoiding the first few rows which contain titles.

I'm also trying to avoid creating duplicate entries but would really appreciate any guidance on that.

Right now I do get some entries but an error code.  It works flawlessly when just targeting a 4x4 array.  ie. sheet get range B2:E:4

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTkX8Go_2lvG3apGJXRX5IOjp6hS4XEWXeqvxwuC29ZFpiuPbhVfk3-p-CIvHCsf9iPMtGU_qN2XpDq/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&widget=true&headers=false

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
    .addItem('Add Events', 'scheduleEvents')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Ignore Errors! :)', 'scheduleEvents')
    .addToUi();
}

function menu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Synced');
}

function scheduleEvents() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  const calendarId = sheet.getRange("P2").getValue();
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  const signups = sheet.getRange("B4:D502").getValues();

   for (let x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {

    const shift = signups[x];

    const startTime = shift[0];
    const endTime = shift[1];
    const title = shift[2];

    eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep a record of the events that you have already created

Answer (score 1):

The reason your script was not working is because the function [createEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime) is using Date objects in the parameters. In your current script you are using `shift[0]` and `shift[1]` which is still a string.

You may try the following to your `scheduleEvents` function:

```
function scheduleEvents() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const calendarId = sheet.getRange("P2").getValue();
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  // Specified the range used for the script
  const signups = sheet.getRange(4, 2, ss.getLastRow() - 3, 3).getValues();

  for (let x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    const shift = signups[x];
    // Converted to a date object
    const startTime = new Date(shift[0]);
    // Converted to a date object
    const endTime = new Date(shift[1]);
    const title = shift[2];

    // Gets the events currently on the calendar based on the startTime and endTime date objects
    const getEvents = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, { search: title });
    // Conditional statement to check if the event's already on the calendar
    if (getEvents == 0) {
      // Adds the event if not yet
      eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
      console.log(${title} has been added to the calendar);
    } else {
      // Gives a message on the console that the event's already on the calendar
      console.log(${title} has already been added to the calendar);
    }
  }
}
```

I've added comments to what I changed and added to your script.

##### What it looks like to add an event:

[image]

##### What it looks like if an event is already on the calendar and adding new ones:

[image]

##### Input in Google Sheets:

[image]

##### Sample output from Google Calendar:

[image]

Notice that a duplicate event for 6am Onboarding was not created because of the conditional statement.